# How to make a list with elements to list with list with only one element?

Tags: python

I have a list with n elements but i would like to convert it to a list which contains n list, and every list contains a single element.

```
 a = ['1','2','3','4']
 b = [['1'],['2'],['3'],['4']]
```

How can I make from a to b?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try list comprehension

```
b = [[i] for i in a]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map`:

```
b = list(map(lambda x: [x], a))
```

or a list comprehension:

```
b = [[i] for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the `a` list and append new list with the item to `b` list.

```
a = ['1','2','3','4']
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append([a[i]])

print(b)
```

This is basically the same solution as the one from JRodDynamite, but more readable for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

**Very Simple Solution Could be from generators**

```
 a = ['1','2','3','4']
 b = [[item] for item in a]
```

Comment: If you convert the generator to a list you can simply use a list comprehension.